# Click one more time on a button after popping the page

Tags: flutter

I get an error when I click on the second time on the "GO" button. For instance, I click on the GO button, then I go back, I click on more time on the GO button => an error pops.

Here is my code :

```
class GoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute;

  GoWidget(this.materialPageRoute) : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 24,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, materialPageRoute);
        },
        child: Text("GO"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my error :

```
I/flutter ( 3069): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 3069): Cannot install a MaterialPageRoute<dynamic> after disposing it.
I/flutter ( 3069): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart':
I/flutter ( 3069): Failed assertion: line 201 pos 12: '!_transitionCompleter.isCompleted'
I/flutter ( 3069): 
I/flutter ( 3069): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 3069): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 3069): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 3069):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

I've already tried to replace

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, materialPageRoute);
},
```

by

```
onPressed: () {
    (() => Navigator.push(context, materialPageRoute))();
},
```

Same problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reuse `MaterialPageRoute` after navigation has been completed. Create a new route every navigation.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MaterialPageRoute route = MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => Scaffold(
        body: const Center(child: Text('PAGE 2')),
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context1) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // ERROR: reusing route.
                // Navigator.push(context1, route);
                // OK: create new route.
                Navigator.push(
                  context1,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                      body: const Center(child: Text('PAGE 2')),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('To page 2'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```